# Conflito ao carregar jQuery na página

Tags: jquery

Creio que esteja com algum conflito de jQuery.
Tenho nesta página, entre outros, o link

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Quando eu comento esta linha, a página aparece, conforme esta imagem. Quero que fique assim,

[image]

mas o menu *acordion* e *faq acordion* não funcionam.

Se eu descomentar este link do Ajax o menu e *faq acordion* voltam a funcionar, mas o cabeçalho fica como esta imagem.

[image]

Como descobrir onde esta o erro? Como consertar isto?

OBS.: Não entendo nada de jQuery

Comment: Eu não entendi sua dúvida, mas poste seu código fonte aqui, que com certeza conseguiremos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Consegue postar o código? 
O que esta acontecendo é que sem o jquery ele não converte os itens (tipo a lista de seleção) e quando você usa ele, é gerado os componentes. Você vai ter que fazer as correções de layout no CSS

Comment: O que você não quer que apareça na imagem ? não ficou claro

Comment: O código completo é longo, como sou novato, não sei se é permito postar script longo

Comment: O código quase completo é de 388 linhas, como posso enviar se o limite aqui é pequeno?

Comment: Se você abrir a página no chrome e apertar `F-12`, aparece algum erro no `console` ou na aba `Network`? Caso a `Network` esteja vazia, recarregue a página com o console aberto.

Comment: @RicoGaucho dá uma olhada nesse artigo http://imasters.com.br/artigo/13871/jquery/evitando-conflitos-com-jquerynoconflict/

Comment: no chrome não aparece erro.
quanto ao artigo, eu já havia lido algo parecido, mas não sei onde exatamente é o conflito.

Comment: Pode postar o HTML. Pelo menos o trecho do select que está mudando quando ativa a jquery...

Comment: Olá, Rico, você é livre para [edit] sua pergunta e acrescentar novas informações. Não pode converter a pergunta em outra coisa, mas não tem problema nenhum em fazer updates quando alguém faz um comentário pedindo mais informação. Como pode ver, aqui nos comentários o código fica ilegível...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar a tag de retirar conflito https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ como no link do jQuery.

Mas creio que seja alguma classe do seu AJAX que está usando essa classe. É melhor se publicar algumas linhas do código para nos ajudar a resolver o problema...

Comment: Olá, Dom. Aqui as assinaturas são proibidas, preencha seu perfil que seu avatar vai aparecer em todas suas respostas e perguntas. Essa é nossa assinatura. Valeu!

Comment: Retirado de todos.. Vou mudar Obrigado.